# Could you help me with this lyrics, please?

Tags: lyrics

> This is the story of ma Baker the meanest cat from old Chicago town
>
> She was the meanest cat
>
> In old Chicago town
>
> She was the **meanest** cat
>
> She really **mowed** them down
>
> She had no heart at all.

What the words "mean" and "mowed somebody down" mean here?
I really need to translate this to Farsi, but in order to translate I should understand it first. Could you paraphrase it and ecplain the use of the highlighted words here, please?
Mow somebody down, is it idiom?
Does the word "mean" here mean "wild" ? Am I right?

Comment: "this lyrics"  is wrong. "lyrics" is a plural noun. It can mean the text of one song or several songs. Correct: these lyrics. - One of the numerous numerus particularities in English. I'm wondering whether "song text" wouldn't be simpler and better than "lyrics".

Answer (score 2):

**Mean** is used as a synonym for *unkind*, *spiteful* or *cruel*. The **-est** is a *Superlative*:

> SUPERLATIVE
>
> 1  :   of, relating to, or constituting the degree of grammatical
>   comparison that denotes an extreme or unsurpassed level or extent

In this case, *meanest* is as mean as mean can get.

**Mowed** is the past-tense for *to mow*.

> MOW
>
> verb
>
> 1.cut down (an area of grass) with a machine

The common expression is, "I'm going out to mow the lawn." It is a weekend ritual in suburban areas during the warmer months.

*Mowed them down* is being used as an idiom **comparing** *how she casually killed people* **to** *the ease of pushing a lawn mower*.

That's one mean cat.

Answer (score 0):

"To mow down people" is a metaphor. If a gangster mows down a lot of people in a busy street with his submachine gun this evokes the picture of a farmer mowing a wheat field with his scythe. The stalks fall down with one stroke.